# Relationship field in a grid

Tags: ee2, relationships, grid

I have a Grid field and in the grid I have relationship field.  I can not seem to get anything to display for the relationship entry. I am using a custom status for my products and in the relationship setup in the grid I have chosen a custom status, not the Open status, this seems to return no results but if I setup products status to Open instead of the custom status then it returns the product information.

The following works if the status is set to Open but not if it is a custom status

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="video_gallery" dynamic="off" url_title="{segment_3}"}
    {video_gallery}
        <div style="float: left; margin: 20px;">
            <a class="youtube" data-id="{video_gallery:video_id}" data-title="{video_gallery:title}" data-description="{video_gallery:description}" data-product="{video_gallery:product search:status='wall'}<a href='/products/{video_gallery:product:url_title}'>{video_gallery:product:product_display_title}</a>{/video_gallery:product}"><img src="{video_gallery:thumbnail}" /></a>
            <br />{title}
        </div>
    {/video_gallery}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What do I need to do to get this to work? Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the template code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

In your example code this:

```
{video_gallery:product search:status='wall'}
```

... is theoretically telling the relationship field to only display entries which have a custom field named `status` with a value of "wall". (Although Relationship field tags do not actually support the `search` parameter - [see supported parameters](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#parameters).)

If you're talking about the `status` as determined by each related entry's "Status" menu, you want this syntax instead:

```
{video_gallery:product status='wall'}
```

Comment: I have already tried this:

`{video_gallery:product status='wall'}`

That did not work either, that is why I had the search parameter in there instead.

Comment: Have you tried a `not` status? `status="not closed"`?

Comment: Looks like that might have done the job.  THANK YOU!!!!!  The big question I have is why that would work versus checking for the custom status.

Comment: Glad that worked - and good question. Could be a bug, or - are you positive that the status you were passing exactly matches the status in EE?

Comment: Yes I am positive about the status, I use that in a few other templates and it works fine